# Animate border of an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a button, that should be swipable, so I want to animate it to communicate it's capability to swipe. The animation should look similarly to the one in native Samsung phones when receiving a call (the one on the buttons), as can be seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FRvMm-QXcY
I have tried to add an image view with a background drawable (white circle) and then scale x and y with an animation, but obviously this scales the whole image, not just the background drawable. I've been wondering how to animate the circle around the image instead of the image itself. Adding the circle as a background may already be a wrong approach, so I don't necessarily need to stick to that.
Here's my code so far:

```
<de.utils.customViews.SwipableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/accept_call_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/accept_call"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_accept_call"
                    android:background="@drawable/swipe_circle"
                    />
```

```
public class SwipableImageView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public SwipableImageView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public SwipableImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SwipableImageView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.swipable);
        startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

and the (so far) animation swipable (I know I also have to work with alpha, but I wanted to figure out how to only animate the circle first):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    >
    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
</set>
```

Comment: This might help : https://youtu.be/EXR47xeo3cA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the answers of @Ruslan and @Cheticamp I came to the following solution:

Create Framelayout for animated button:

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/accept_call_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

     <de.example.utils.customViews.SwipeAnimationView
           android:layout_width="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:src="@drawable/swipe_circle" />

     <de.example.utils.customViews.SwipableImageView
           android:layout_width="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/accept_hangup_call_button"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:contentDescription="@string/accept_call"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/anim_margin"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_accept_call"
           />
</FrameLayout>
```

The call button (SwipableImageView) has an animation margin, which makes the framelayout align in size to the current icons size + the space the animation will take up.

Then I have the SwipeAnimationView with an init()-function that just calls the animation:

```
public void init() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.swipable);
        startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

This function gets called in every constructor.
The animation then is in the following xml (by now also with alpha changes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    >
    <scale
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        />
</set>
```

The swipe_circle is just an oval, as Android Studio wouldn't display a ring shape. However, as the other icon overlays it, it works perfectly fine to just adapt the size. For continuos centering however, the pivotX and pivotY need to be considered in the animation.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be much simpler to implement this in a 'hamburger' style - so you will have static `SwipableImageView` and a separate `Animation` view, which you simply put below your main ImageView.

By doing so we will receive little bit more of GPU overdraws, because of views nesting. But that shouldn't be critical at all, since it will take only small area of screen.

Also you can implement this 'hamburger' as a CompoundView, so it will be easier to reuse across the app if needed.

**UPDATE**

Sample implementation using `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/animationBorder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too. But I couldn't find a stack pane layout in Android, so I wondered how to put them on top of each other without going insane with constraints.

Comment: @SarahMultitasker FrameLayout would be perfectly fine for your case, it does what you need - puts its child views on top of each other. Don't forget to put your animation view first, so it goes under your image view. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To address Ruslan's idea in a little more detail, for the animation drawable in back, you could use two drawables - one for the white center circle and one for the expanding ring.

**center_circle.xml**

```
<inset 
    android:insetLeft="@dimen/swipeable_padding"
    android:insetTop="@dimen/swipeable_padding"
    android:insetRight="@dimen/swipeable_padding"
    android:insetBottom="@dimen/swipeable_padding">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

You would use this as the background in an *ImageView*. The insets make room for the ring around the circle. For the expanding ring:

**expanding_ring.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:innerRadius="34dp"
    android:useLevel="true">
    <solid android:color="#55ffffff" />
</shape>
```

This would be the `src` for the animation *ImageView*.

You will need to set the level for the ring drawable to 10,000 programatically for anything to show.

Now, in code, you would use a [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator) to change the ring's thickness to go from zero to a value that will fill the *ImageView*. Unfortunately, to change the thickness programmatically, your app will need a minSdk of 29 or greater.

Another idea which would work for any API is to write a drawable class that will simply draw the expanding ring directly onto the canvas. The signature for this class would be

```
class SwipeableBackground extends Drawable implements Animatable
```

and it would be set as the background to a single *ImageView* that will also hold the phone icon as the `src`. In this class you can also use the [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator) to assist in growing the ring.

In both cases, you would create another *ValueAnimator* to fade the ring as the end of expansion. The two animators would be placed into an [AmimatorSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet) which would repeat indefinitely or until stopped.

There may be some libraries that can easily do this animation if you want to go that route.